# Analogy between Autoencoder and PCA

Tags: autoencoder, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I know that Autoencoders can be regarded as non-linear generalisations of PCA, but I struggle to understand in depth the analogy between the two.

Once PCA has been performed on a function $F(\vec{\theta})$ of the parameters $\vec{\theta}$, that function can be re-written as

$F(\vec{\theta}) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_{\mathrm{PCA}}} \alpha_i(\vec{\theta}) \, b_i$,

where $b_i$ are the PCA basis functions and $\alpha_i (\vec{\theta})$ the $N_{\rm{PCA}}$ PCA coefficients.

For Autoencoders, one can also build **basis functions**, by decoding the basis vectors $(1, 0, \dots 0), (0, 1, \dots 0), \dots (0, 0, \dots, 1)$ through the decoder, once the Autoencoder has been trained. Can a function $F(\vec{\theta})$ still be rewritten as $F(\vec{\theta}) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_{\mathrm{AE}}} \alpha_i(\vec{\theta}) \, b_i$, where $N_{\mathrm{AE}}$ is the number of encoded features in the central layer of the Autoencoder?